# what is the purpose of Completer, if not await in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, controller, future

Here is the code:

```
Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
...
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller.complete(controller);
  }
```

What is the purpose of the 2nd row in this code.

Comment: it is pointless to call `complete` and not using the `Completer` at all - where did you get that code from?

Comment: and now? how can be used that controller?

Comment: `_controller.future.then()` for example, or in any method that needs a `Future`

Comment: The point of using a `Completer` is to be able to create a `Future` that can be directly controlled.  The rest of the above code presumably has `await _controller.future` somewhere to be notified when the `onMapCreated` callback fires.

Comment: thank you dude, i just used and solved my problem with "method is called on null" problem